# npm install is building the world

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

```
npm install grunt --save -dev
```

Downloading and building all of the dependencies is taking forever (and large). Previously it was rather quick. Anyone else been experiencing this?

[image]

Comment: That's `--save-dev`, not `--save -dev`.

Answer (score 3):

That's `--save-dev`, not `--save -dev`.